# Grid not refreshing with new record when rebinded but new record is found when filtering

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendogrid and when I add a new record and rebind the grid, the new record is not in the grid, however if I use the filter for it then I see it, but to actually see it in the grid I have to refresh my page.

When the page loads it calls this function

```
function GetCustomerGridData() {
    kendo.ui.progress($("#Customer-Grid"), true);
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: URLParam.GetActiveCustomersForTheGrid,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            LoadCustomerGrid(data);
            kendo.ui.progress($("#Customer-Grid"), false);
        }
    });
}
```

The LoadCustomerGrid is this

```
function LoadCustomerGrid(newData) {    
    CreateCustomerGrid(newData);
}
```

The grid itself is..

```
var customerGrid,
    CreateCustomerGrid = function (newData) {
        customerGrid = $("#Customer-Grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: {
                data: newData
            },
            schema: {
                model: {
                    CustomerID: { type: "number" }
                }
            },
            filterable: {
                mode: "row"
            },
            columns: [
                {
                    template: "<input type='checkbox' class='checkbox' />",
                    width: "30px"
                }
            {
                field: "LastName",
                title: "Last Name",
                filterable: {
                    cell: {
                        showOperators: false,
                        operator: "contains",
                        inputHeight: "34px"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                field: "FirstName",
                title: "Name",
                filterable: {
                    cell: {
                        showOperators: false,
                        operator: "contains"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                field: "Phone",
                title: "Phone",
                filterable: {
                    cell: {
                        showOperators: false,
                        operator: "contains"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                field: "Address",
                title: "Address",
                filterable: {
                    cell: {
                        showOperators: false,
                        operator: "contains"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                field: "City",
                title: "City",
                filterable: {
                    cell: {
                        showOperators: false,
                        operator: "contains"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                field: "Zip",
                title: "Zip",
                filterable: {
                    cell: {
                        showOperators: false,
                        operator: "contains"
                    }
                }
            }
            ],
            scrollable: true,
            sortable: true,
            pageable: {
                pageSize: 20
            },
            selectable: "row",
            height: $("#Customer-Grid").closest(".col-height-full").height() - 60,
            change: function (e) {
                // Function call goes here
                var detailRow = this.dataItem(this.select());
                var optionID = detailRow.get("CustomerID")
            }
        }).data("kendoGrid");
    }
```

When I go to add a record I use a popup

```
function CustomerPopupEditor() {
    $("#showCustomerEdit").append("<div id='window'></div>");
    var myWindow = $("#window").kendoWindow({
        position: {
            top: 100,
            left: "30%"
        },
        width: "40%",
        title: "Add Customer",
        content: "/Customer/CustomerEditor",
        modal: true,
        actions: [
            "Close"
        ],
        close: function (e) {
            $("#window").data("kendoWindow").destroy();
        }
    }).data("kendoWindow");
    myWindow.open();
    GetStates();
    HomeStorage.Keys.AddOrEdit = "Add";
}
```

and when add a new record and click the save button, this function is called

```
function SubmitNewCustomer() {
    var customer = NewCustomerToSubmit();
    GetAssignmentIDs();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: URLParam.AddNewCustomer + "?assignments=" + HomeStorage.Keys.AssignmentIDString,
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: JSON.stringify(customer),
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            HomeStorage.Keys.NewCustomerID = data.id;            
        },
        complete: function (e) {
            GetCustomerGridData();
            ClearFields();
        }
    })
}
```

and when I close the popup on a button click event this is called

```
$("#btnCancel").click(function () {
    ClearFields();
    GetCustomerGridData();
    CloseTheWindow();
});
```

In the SubmitNewCustomer function I have tried putting the GetCustomerGridData() in its success function and that didnt work either.

The data being returned for the GetCustomerGridData() has over 30K records, but I dont think that should matter much.

Any idea what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for the issue that I was running into, I should destroy the grid as well so I added this line of code

```
$('#Customer-Grid').data('kendoGrid').destroy();
```

I added this to my CloseTheWindow() method then rebinded the grid and the newly added record appears without having to refresh the page.